# Django REST: Allow foreign key to be get_or_created() in POST/PUT

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a situation where I need to be able to POST to a resource and have a specific foreign key relation automatically "get_or_create()ed".

I'm going to make up an example here for simplicity:

Let's assume I want to post a new address and city is a foreign key -- and there are millions of cities.  The city resource might have other attributes, like population, country, etc., but for this example assume that they default to NULL and that is Ok.

```
address: { street: "...", city: "..." }

city: { name: "...", population: 10000, ... }
```

I have a couple of problems:

- When I use the django rest HTML interface, it tries to add all of the cities to an HTML option box which hangs the browser because there are too many options.  I don't want a drop down option box.  A text box is what I need.
- When I submit a city I want the create/update code to find the city based on the name and set the relation, OR I want it to create a new one.  Essentially a get_or_create() on the city's name field.  I don't want the user to have to POST to create a new city for every new city before they add an address.

So I need to somehow tell DRF that city is a relation that I want displayed as text like a SlugRelatedField, but I don't want it as a selectable enumeration.  I also don't want to set it to read_only (which would fix the dropdown box problem.)

What do I need to look at to glue this together?  I assume I need to make some kind of custom field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the right way to do this:  Derive from `serializers.CharField` and override  `to_internal_value()` to `get_or_create()`:

```
class CityField(serializers.CharField):

   def to_internal_value(self, data):
       value = super(CityField, self).to_internal_value(data)
       return City.objects.get_or_create(name=value)[0]
```